# JDBC Remote MySQL Connectivity

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm developing a Java Swing based app which uses JDBC to connect to a MySQL database. As such, the software directly remotely access the database from whichever computer it happens to be running on. Additionally, the app uses prepared statements to query the database and the database is hosted on a shared CPanel hosting account (if that matters).

The snippet of code I use to connect to the database is as follows (fairly standard connect code I think and all strings in all caps contain the correct contents):

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://URL:PORT/DB_NAME?connectTimeout=3000";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

I have only ever successfully used the app from one IP. Before I use the app from an IP, I have to manually whitelist the IP by adding it as an allowed remote MySQL access host. If I don't add the IP as an allowed access host, the server refuses my connection and I get the resultant error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Then if I whitelist an IP and try to connect from it, I don't get that error and the app connects to the database properly.

This system would be okay if the app were only going to be used from one IP, but it needs to work from any IP since I cannot predict who will download and use it. The only solution I see would be to do a global whitelist of all IPs in the allowed MySQL access hosts area. However, that seems like it has many drawbacks, such as being insecure as anyone who has the correct password could log in (and would thus be susceptible to brute force attacks). [This](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-whitelist-your-ip-in-cpanel-for-remote-mysql-access) seems to corroborate the hypothesis that that method is insecure. Thus, I would like to have a system of communicating between the app and database that is IP-independent (doesn't require whitelisting all the IPs).

Additionally (I don't know if this makes sense or matters), but I believe some of the areas I expect the app to be used in block certain protocols. Thus, (I think) I would like it if the selected method of communication only used HTTP or some other widely-used protocol.

I did some research into this problem and my efforts led me to 2-tier and n-tier models of database communication. Perhaps I could do something like make a PHP page which accepts a statement and a series of parameters (plus a password to gain entry), executes the statement, and then returns the result back as JSON. However, this seems like another less-than-ideal method as it seems like it would also have security problems.

I'm sure someone more experienced and knowledgeable than I has already come across this problem and developed a solution.

Therefore, my question: What is the preferred method of connecting to a MySQL database from a Java app in an IP-independent way?

I greatly appreciate and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track:

1) If you want any arbitrary client to connect directly to your database, and the clients can have any arbitrary IP address ... then you're probably going to have to effectly *disable* IP security be whitelisting *all* possible client IP addresses.

2) On the other hand, if you only allow local access to mySql (by far the most common scenario), then you can create a web app to interface between your clients and mySql.

SUGGESTION:
Consider creating a "REST" web service that your clients can talk to.

Here's a good tutorial that might help you get started:

[REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html)

Q: Does your Swing app really need to emit "raw SQL"?  Or can it make "high level" queries?  REST is ideally suited for the latter.

PS:

Here's another, short example that might help suggest some design alternatives with REST, mySQL and Java for you:

http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/restful-web-services-api-using-java-and.html

Comment: thanks for the advice. Please pardon my ignorance - what is a "high level query"? Currently, it runs queries to obtain data (both detailed and summarized) on a variety of tables in a database. Would this count as raw SQL or a high level query?

Comment: raw SQL: `select * from widgets;`.  High level: `http://example.com/rest/widgetreport?detailed`.  Also read Ollie Jones' comments below.  He's right: opening up mySQL access to other hosts on the network (or worse, to any client on the Internet) opens up a whole can of worms.  I'm advocating writing a simple "Web App" instead of allowing direct mySQL access.  I'm also suggesting that creating a "REST API" for your reports might be an effective way to do this,.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. If I can figure out how to write a REST API (I've never written one before), I probably will (one of the things I'm having trouble understanding/haven't found yet in the tutorials is how to add security [a password] to the API so only my app can access it). I liked Ollie Jones' suggestion of using an SSH tunnel to remotely access the database. If I may ask, in your opinion, which may be better: using an SSH tunnel for remote access or using a REST API (because I honestly don't know)?

Answer (score 1):

You are up against the policies -- primarily the security policies -- of your hosting provider. It's generally considered insecure to allow port 3306 (MySQL) connections from the whole internet. It certainly lays your MySQL server open to trivial denial-of-service attacks. (It just takes some knucklehead controlling a botnet to send in lots of port 3306 connection attempts. They don't even have to be successful connection attempts.) If you're sharing your MySQL server with other customers of your hosting provider, they have every incentive to restrict your remote access to their server.

Most folks who build database applications for deployment on the public internet do it by providing web services to hit the database with the specific operations required by the application. The application deployed at the end-user's machine then uses HTTP (or HTTPS for security) to access those web services. In turn the web services access the database. That's what multitier operations do. You're right that there are security problems, but you can mitigate them with careful development of your web service code.

You could use SSH tunneling to handle your database access. The SSH suite of remote-access applications allows port forwarding. To use this, you would establish (authenticated and encrypted) ssh connections between your end-users' machines and your database machine, that forward port 3306. Then your users could connect to localhost:3306, and that net traffic would be forwarded to your database server.  It's pretty flexible and quite secure, if not completely simple to configure.

You might also investigate using [SQL Relay](http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/).  It's generally used for connection pooling and management within a data center network, but it might work for this purpose.

Be careful opening up your MySQL server to the world! If you do that you may want to require the use of TLS encrypted conections.